# How to apply Selection method to sort in alphabetical order?

Tags: java, arrays, java-8

```
Estudiante[] aux = new Estudiante[1];
int contador = 0;
int contador2 = 1;
for (int i = 1; i < arregloEstudiante.length - 1; i++) {
    String minimo = arregloEstudiante[contador].getCarnet();
    int menor = i;
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arregloEstudiante.length; j++) {
        String maximo = arregloEstudiante[contador2].getCarnet();
        if (minimo.compareTo(maximo) < 0) {
            menor = j;
        }
        if (menor == j) {
            aux[0] = arregloEstudiante[i];
            arregloEstudiante[i] = arregloEstudiante[menor];
            arregloEstudiante[menor] = aux[0];
        }
    }
    contador++;
    contador2++;
}
return arregloEstudiante;
```

This is the my closest result.

```
C54411
B92542
A95720
A22523
B4562
B32567
B42667
C72588
C42214
C34767
```

We have to use Selection method. using this array

```
        arregloEstudiante[0] = new Estudiante("C54411", "Maria", "Mora Mora", 700);
        arregloEstudiante[1] = new Estudiante("B92542", "Jose", "Solano Solano", 444);
        arregloEstudiante[2] = new Estudiante("C42214", "Alonso", "Solano Mora", 800);
        arregloEstudiante[3] = new Estudiante("A95720", "Miguel", "Mora Solano", 550);
        arregloEstudiante[4] = new Estudiante("B32567", "Andrea", "Jimenez Ureña", 625);
        arregloEstudiante[5] = new Estudiante("C34767", "Fabian", "Sanchez Alvarado", 740);
        arregloEstudiante[6] = new Estudiante("C72588", "Martin", "Moya Ureña", 592);
        arregloEstudiante[7] = new Estudiante("B42667", "Fabiana", "Sanchez Alvarado", 689);
        arregloEstudiante[8] = new Estudiante("A22523", "Mariano", "Mora Mora", 750);
        arregloEstudiante[9] = new Estudiante("B4562", "Alonso", "Solano Morales", 497);
```

only using the first attribute, I save them in temp, "minimo" and "maximo"`
This is the my closest result.

```
C54411
B92542
A95720
A22523
B4562
B32567
B42667
C72588
C42214
C34767
```

I have to use Selection order methods. Using this array, I have to make an alphabetical order, with the first attribute, I save them in temp "minimo" and "maximo".

I use this class.

```
public class Estudiante {

private String carnet;
private String nombre;
private String apellidos;
private int notaAdmision;

public Estudiante() {

}

public Estudiante(String carnet, String nombre, String apellidos, int notaAdmision) {
    this.carnet = carnet;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
    this.notaAdmision = notaAdmision;
}

public String getCarnet() {
    return this.carnet;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return this.nombre;
}

public String getApellidos() {
    return this.apellidos;
}

public int getNotaAdmision() {
    return this.notaAdmision;
}

public void setCarnet(String carnet) {
    this.carnet = carnet;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
    this.apellidos = apellidos;
}

public void setNotaAdmision(int notaAdmision) {
    this.notaAdmision = notaAdmision;
}
```

This is my class I think everything is ok.
I have to use the selection order method.
If someone finds a solution please tell me.
Compiles with JAVA 1.8

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, it seems you forgot to ask a question, or at least you didn't word it as a question, so please read [ask]. In fact, you claim that "everything is ok", which if true means you don't really have a question because your code works. Congratulations if that's the case. If, however, not everything is ok, you should tell us what is not working: what input are you using, what output do you expect, and what output do you actually get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) to sort the array of `Estudiante` according to the `carnet` attribute.

I copied the code from [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-selection-sort) Web page and modified it to suit your needs.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Estudiante {
    private String carnet;
    private String nombre;
    private String apellidos;
    private int notaAdmision;

    public Estudiante(String carnet, String nombre, String apellidos, int notaAdmision) {
        this.carnet = carnet;
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
        this.notaAdmision = notaAdmision;
    }

    public String getCarnet() {
        return this.carnet;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return this.nombre;
    }

    public String getApellidos() {
        return this.apellidos;
    }

    public int getNotaAdmision() {
        return this.notaAdmision;
    }

    public void setCarnet(String carnet) {
        this.carnet = carnet;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public void setApellidos(String apellidos) {
        this.apellidos = apellidos;
    }

    public void setNotaAdmision(int notaAdmision) {
        this.notaAdmision = notaAdmision;
    }

    public static void sortAscending(final Estudiante[] arr) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            int minElementIndex = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[minElementIndex].getCarnet().compareTo(arr[j].getCarnet()) > 0) {
                    minElementIndex = j;
                }
            }
            if (minElementIndex != i) {
                Estudiante temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[minElementIndex];
                arr[minElementIndex] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Estudiante[] arregloEstudiante = new Estudiante[10];
        arregloEstudiante[0] = new Estudiante("C54411", "Maria", "Mora Mora", 700);
        arregloEstudiante[1] = new Estudiante("B92542", "Jose", "Solano Solano", 444);
        arregloEstudiante[2] = new Estudiante("C42214", "Alonso", "Solano Mora", 800);
        arregloEstudiante[3] = new Estudiante("A95720", "Miguel", "Mora Solano", 550);
        arregloEstudiante[4] = new Estudiante("B32567", "Andrea", "Jimenez Ureña", 625);
        arregloEstudiante[5] = new Estudiante("C34767", "Fabian", "Sanchez Alvarado", 740);
        arregloEstudiante[6] = new Estudiante("C72588", "Martin", "Moya Ureña", 592);
        arregloEstudiante[7] = new Estudiante("B42667", "Fabiana", "Sanchez Alvarado", 689);
        arregloEstudiante[8] = new Estudiante("A22523", "Mariano", "Mora Mora", 750);
        arregloEstudiante[9] = new Estudiante("B4562", "Alonso", "Solano Morales", 497);
        sortAscending(arregloEstudiante);
        Arrays.stream(arregloEstudiante)
              .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getCarnet()));
    }
}
```

- The only method I added was `sortAscending()`.
- The last lines of the code simply print out the sorted array. They do not affect the actual sort operation. You can use any method you like to print out the sorted array – if you need to print it out at all.

Below is the output I get when running the above code.

```
A22523
A95720
B32567
B42667
B4562
B92542
C34767
C42214
C54411
C72588
```